# Can I use the ESP-01 (ESP8266) to connect securely to MQTT broker?

Tags: mqtt, esp8266

The latest ESP-WROOM-02 support TLS1.2 over AT commands (I got this confirmed by Expressif). However I would like to use the ESP-01 unmodified to connect to an MQTT-broker, using TLS1.2. Is it possible to use the ESP01? Does it use the same firmware or codebase? I can't seem to find concrete answers.

Note that my app runs on another MCU (unavoidable). In principle I could reflash the ESP module, but that would add a step in the production process, plus yet another development environment. An advantage would be that the ESP01 firmware version would be strictly known.

I've seen that many advise to reflash the ESP with an Arduino derived firmware aka [WiFiClientSecure](https://io.adafruit.com/blog/security/2016/07/05/adafruit-io-security-esp8266/) and thus avoid working with the AT-commands (indeed I found NO library to specifically (and reliably) work with them).

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about security, then ESP8266 family modules (such as the ESP-01, ESP-WROOM-02, D1, NodeMCU) are likely not a practical choice.

They don't provide a mechanism for encrypting credentials on the device or a way to ensure that no one has altered the code that's running, and you end up in a situation like this one: https://thehackernews.com/2016/01/doorbell-hacking-wifi-pasword.html

However, the ESP-32 does provide that. It also allows you to make a secure MQTT connection. While it's more expensive than the ESP-01, it's still pretty affordable (about $6 on AliExpress).

Comment: Well, at this stage I hardly know how credentials _should_ be treated. So I am taking your advice to heart. BTW, the ESP32, to my surprise, is down to $3.50, which is excellent value and makes this almost a no-brainer. Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score -1):

The doorbell hack example is just stupid.
Why didn't they add a password for the Access Point connection.